# take Duplicated ID's out and Identify a new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case-statement

I Joined 6 table together to gather all information that I need.
I want all Id's, Names, Birthdays, and Ethnicity.
Some Ids have 2 or more Ethnicity and that will cause a id be duplicated.
I am thinking of writing a sub query or can I just use a case statement since I have tried case statement before and works for another case but I can not apply it in this case.

what I have is:

```
ID             NAME                  Birthdays                   Ethnicity
4000           Pedram                11/11/1999                  Middle East
4001           Carlos                11/11/1920                  Spanish 
4001           Carlos                11/11/1920                  Native American
4002           Asia                  11/22/1986                  Polish
4002           Asia                  11/22/1986                  Native American
4002           Asia                  11/22/1986                 White/caucassian
```

I want to say if any Id duplicated and ethnicity is different <> just give me this:

```
ID             NAME                  Birthdays                   Ethnicity
4000           Pedram                11/11/1999                  Middle East
4001           Carlos                11/11/1920                  Multiracial
4002           Asia                  11/22/1986                  multiracial
```

PS : ethnicity is in a different table and I joined it to Person_table
PS : to be able to join ethnicity table to Person_table I needed to join 3 more tables that have pr keys that can related to each other.
PS : I tried CASE WHEN Count (Id) > 1 THEN 'Multiracial' ELSE Ethnicity END AS Ethnicity_2
and it Identify all ethnicity as Multiracial.

Any help Or thought will be appreciate.

Comment: sooo...MySQL, Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: sql server is what I am using

Comment: in the future only tag the rdbms you are actually using, I have removed the oracle and mysql tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID),
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Ethnicity)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  ID,
        NAME,
        Birthdays,
        CASE WHEN N > 1 THEN 'Multiracial' ELSE Ethnicity END Ethnicity
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: What if The have the same Ethnicity twice?  I know OP doesn't specify that it could or could not be the case but count(*) would be > 1 then....

Comment: @Matt You are right, and really, my query doesn't make much sense at all, a simple `GROUP BY` would do

Comment: it makes since and is actually an easier way to think through the logic sometimes! cheers up vote for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    id, name, Birthdays,
    IIF(COUNT(DISTINCT Ethnicity) > 1, 'Multiracial', MIN(Ethnicity)) as Ethnicity
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    id, name, Birthdays

SELECT
    id, name, Birthdays,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Ethnicity) > 1 THEN 'Multiracial' ELSE MIN(Ethnicity) END as Ethnicity
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    id, name, Birthdays
```

Comment: IIF statement does not Work on sql 2016?

Comment: works on 2012 & 2014 pretty sure it is 2012 + are you having an issue with it?

Comment: @PedramSalamati I put in a case expression method that will work on most RDBMS's

Answer (score 1):

This one might not be the most efficient but it works. Just substitute your derived table for t below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.name,
CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN ethnicity
ELSE 'Multiracial' END AS ethnicity
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT ethnicity) AS cnt
 FROM t
 GROUP BY id) sub
ON t.id = sub.id
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7473f/6